# Drawing in Java without a JPanel

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel

I'm writing a graphical user interface to plot data on a xy-axis.  It's written in Java Swing so I have a `JFrame` that contains the whole GUI.  One of the components of the GUI is a `JPanel` that makes up the area where the data is plotted.  I use `Graphics2D` to do my drawing.

I'm trying to make a command line extension of this program.  The idea is that the user can specify the data that they want plotted in a config file.  This allows for interesting parameter sweeps that save a lot of time.

The problem occurs when I try to obtain a `Graphics` object to draw with.  I create the `JPanel` that does the drawing, but the `Graphics` object is null when I call `paintComponent()`.

Also, when you run the program (from command line again), it steals focus from whatever else you're trying to do (if this program is running in the background).  Is there anyway to get around that?  Do you have to create a `JPanel` to do drawing?

Thanks for any help provided!

P.S.  When I say that I'm running the program from command line, I mean to say that you are not using the GUI.  All of the plotting, etc. is being done without an interface.  Also, I'm aware that you can't instantiate a `Graphics` object.

Comment: What do you want do draw on when you are running from a command line? Are you trying to use the terminal/console/command prompt as a drawing canvas?

Or do you mean that the program is started without a GUI, and needs to create a JFrame to plot on?

Comment: Interesting. You have to create the Graphics from somewhere. It is possible to create a Graphics instance using the printer API, probably you could look in that path.  I would try to configure a "file printer" of some sort ant then get that printjob.  Probably that will give you a Graphics object. Take a look at http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/PrintJob.html

Comment: @MikeD - In the end I want the graph to be saved to a JPEG.  I'm not terribly concerned what I'm drawing on.  It would be nice to use the same code that does the drawing on the JPanel though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a java.awt.image.BufferedImage

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();

//.. draw stuff ..

ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("png").next();
writer.setOutput(ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(new File("myimage.png"));
writer.write(image);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using GUI, you need to use [headless mode](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/)
This will provide you proper graphics environment.
You will have to either execute with an option such as

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true
```

or
Set property in your main class such as:

> System.setProperty("java.awt.headless",
>   "true");

Please check out the link for more programmatic examples.

Comment: Thanks!  This helped with the problem of losing focus.  I wish that I could accept both of these answers.

Comment: @Ryan - good to know; just as side note, if you are planning to use your software on Unix environment, you would have to install something called "virtual frame buffer" and start its services; so that headless mode works properly with X11.